# jQuery Virtual keyboard and the sliding down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I used jQuery virtual keyboard, but I found problem when I click on the password field several times the keyboard slides down, I checked the css and I have dont found a solution.
Someone has an idea ?

This is the link :

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/jquery-virtual-keyboard-with-qwerty.html

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried using it in this fiddle and it works http://jsfiddle.net/TUAHC/. The key difference is that I used the latest version of jQuery, 1.8.2 instead of version 1.4.4 that was used in the demo you posted. Upgrading the jQuery version seems to fix the issue.

**EDIT**

It seems that there's an issue with the jQuery UI Position utility used in the plugin which is called on each time the text input is focused, and it seems to only manifest itself when there's padding/margin on the parent element. A way of fixing it would be to modify the plugin and move the positioning code of the plugin outside the focus event handler. So find this code (around line 141 of the plugin js file):

```
element.focus(function() {
  var element = jQuery(this)
  jQuery('.ui-keyboard').hide();
  previewInput.val(element.val());

  keyboard.position({
    of: element,
    my: "left top",
    at: "left top",
    collision: "fit",
  }).show();

  previewInput.scrollTop(previewInput.attr('scrollHeight')).focus();
});
```

And change the code to this:

```
keyboard.position({
  of: element,
  my: "left top",
  at: "left top",
  collision: "fit",
});

element.focus(function() {
  var element = jQuery(this)
  jQuery('.ui-keyboard').hide();
  previewInput.val(element.val());

  keyboard.show();

  previewInput.scrollTop(previewInput.attr('scrollHeight')).focus();
});
```

That seems to do the trick in my tests http://jsfiddle.net/TUAHC/2/.

Comment: So upgrading jQuery fixes it in your case as well?

Comment: No I upgrade jQuery and I have the same problem

Comment: @Mils I've updated my answer with a solution. Check it out and see if it works for you

Comment: Hey Spider,
Can I apply this library on a text field dynamically created ?
Thank you.

Comment: Yes. You just need to bind the plugin to the new input element after you create it.

Comment: Hi again,
I try to add an action to the button accept with jquery, but it's not work, but without the library it's work, this is what I added :


jQuery('#some_text_box').live('input', function() {
    // do your stuff
})

Have you an idea ?
Thank you.

Comment: Create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with what you are attempting so I can see the code. You modify the one I've setup in my original answer http://jsfiddle.net/TUAHC/ (as it has the keyboard plugin already added to the resources section). Also, as a side note: I assume you are referring to the Accept button of the keyboard.

Comment: Thank you very much.
What I wanna do is : when you uncomment the library of keyboard the alert is not work in this link : http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/13/

I want to add some action to the accept button

Comment: Hello,
You understand what I mean, when I insert text without virtual keyboard I cant detect the action but with the keyboard I can't.
Thank you.

Comment: This http://jsfiddle.net/W2xFX/16/ adds a callback to the accept button click action. Is that what you want?

Comment: Yeah just I want for every text field I have a different action :
http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/20/

Comment: I try this http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/24/ with multiple selector but its not work

Comment: Spider I resolve the problem in this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12843000/action-with-multiple-attribute-selector-jquery/12843415#12843415
Thank you.

Comment: Hey Spider,
I tried to add a virtual keyboard to my code using jQuery, in fact I have several text fields and I added to each on this keybord. My problem is when I load the page it take many times (~ 10 seconds) to display. You have an idea?

This is my [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/TUAHC/12/).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your code. It does take about 1-2 seconds to build all the keyboards for 150 input fields but that's to be expected. The problem from what I can see is that [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net) is very slow to respond (so it's the server not your code).

Comment: Hi, I test it in my browser and it's slow

I found a first solution to my problem ; I only call the keyboard when I click in the text box.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/TUAHC/13/).

But it's still a bit slow...