# Action with Multiple Attribute Selector jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, keyboard

I am trying to use a keyboard to enter numeric values.

My problems is the following: the keyboard has a button "Accept" and I have several text fields, I want to add for each text fields a different action. I tried to use multiple attribute selector but is not work.

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" /> </br>
<input id="txt2" type="text" /> </br>
<input id="txt3" type="text" /> </br>
```

---

```
$('input[type=text]').keyboard({
    layout: "num"
});

$('.ui-keyboard').on('click', 'input[name="key_accept"]',function() {
    alert('Accept button was clicked in text1');
    // do your stuff here
});
```

You can show the example in this link http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/25/

The alert is for all text field but I want for each text a different alert.

Comment: What is the text you want to show? How is it different for each one?

Comment: I want for each text field a different action
Something like that : http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/26/
But just only one alert. For example When I modify the second text field I have this alert "Accept button was clicked in text2"

Comment: Well, here's one approach: http://jsfiddle.net/NK9me/ But you should really check the documentation for the plugin you're using to see if they make the original input available in a better way. I have no idea what plugin that is. You should really include that information in the question.

Comment: Sorry how can I get the value in the text field ?

Comment: What is the `keyboard` plugin you're using?

Comment: This one : http://www.devcurry.com/2010/12/jquery-virtual-keyboard-with-qwerty.html

Comment: Thank you I resolve the problem : http://jsfiddle.net/Mils/W2xFX/37/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the component you are using does not expose any event for accept and cancel, an external solution is needed. For example, you can save the current element on focus, and use that inside the accept button event.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/W2xFX/27/

**Code:**

```
var currentKB = null;
$('input[type=text]').focus(function() {
    currentKB = this;
    return true;
});

$('input[type=text]').keyboard({
    layout: "num"
});

$('.ui-keyboard').on('click', 'input[name="key_accept"]',function(e, x) {
    alert('Accept button was clicked in ' + currentKB.id);
    // do your stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/W2xFX/35/

You just have to keep track of the active text box (the last one focused on).